# Self submit modal form so that form elements are reloaded and modal window is not closed

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a form which gets displayed as a pop up modal when a user clicks "Create Test Case" button. The modal itself contains two tabs. One tab displays form fields for test details and the second tab displays form fields for test properties.

In the first tab "tests" if the user fills out the form and clicks "add test" then the form should trigger back end php processing and write data to MYSQL database. The modal form should close as well.  On the other hand, if user clicks the "Properties" tab, it should allow them to add properties dynamically and also insert into mysql database. It should reload the properties page every time a new property is added.

The problem I'm having is that every time I click "Add" on the property page, the Modal window closes.

Can someone tell me how i can get the modal window to reload the properties form page and prevent the modal window from closing each time the Add button is pressed?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="">
    <div class="page-title">
      <div class="title_left">
        <h3>Test Management <small></small></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <!-- start real -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Add Test Cases <small><?php echo $filenamePrefix; ?></small></h2>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
              <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="x_content">
            <p class="text-muted font-13 m-b-30">
              Add new test cases to current project.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Create new test case</button>
            <!-- begin modal-->
            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                         </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new test case</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
                      <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_content1" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Tests</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_content2" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Properties</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <form name="variables" id="variables" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

                          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="span col-md-2">
                                  <label>Test Details</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name="rest_method">
                                <option value="GET">GET</option>
                                <option value="POST">POST</option>
                                <option value="PUST">PUT</option>
                              </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-5">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                                    <button id="addTests" type="submit" value="true" name="addTests" class="btn btn-success">Add Test</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_content2" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="span col-md-4">
                                  <label>Property Name</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="variable_name" name="variable_name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="span col-md-2">
                                  <label>Add Properties</label>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="addVariables" value="true" name="addVariables">Add</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end MyyContentTab-->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end modal body -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /page content -->
```